# Filter On Kendo UI Grid Group Header

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo UI Grid with fields  Student Name ,Height and Age. I am grouping it by age . I can easily apply filterable on Student Name  and  Height columns but is there a way to add a filter text box for Age as well which is a "group field". Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can make that column filterable as well as any other column. http://dojo.telerik.com/usuKi